# Oracle SQL: How to use connect by level based on a condition in select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using connect by to generate a list of hours between date/times that a user enters.
However I need to check whether the end_datetime is null because my generated list of hours won't work if it is null.
So if the user doesn't enter an end date time, I want to use the current hour + 1 as the end_datetime. I'm stuck. I know how to do this for when both end_datetime and start_datetime are there, but how do I handle when end_datetime is null and use current hour + 1?

```
SELECT 
  (TRUNC(START_DATETIME,'dd') + (FLOOR(to_char(START_DATETIME,'sssss')/3600)/24) + ((LEVEL - 1)/ 24)) AS DATE_INTERVAL
FROM STORM_REPORTDATE
CONNECT BY LEVEL < ((24 * (TO_DATE(END_DATETIME, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') - TO_DATE(START_DATETIME, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ) + 1 ) )
```

Comment: Are you looking for `CONNECT BY LEVEL < ((24 * (NVL(TO_DATE(END_DATETIME, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), SYSDATE + 1/24) - ....`?

Comment: @JoshEller already answered your question in the comment above mine. But your whole query is very poorly written; would you be interested in rewriting it in a more readable way?

Comment: Thank you Josh Eller I have read on the usage of NVL() and figured out the correct answer:CONNECT BY LEVEL < ((24 * (NVL(TO_DATE(END_DATETIME, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ) - TO_DATE(START_DATETIME, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ) + 1 ) )

Comment: CONNECT BY LEVEL < ((24 * (NVL(TO_DATE(END_DATETIME, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),TO_DATE(SYSDATE + 1/24, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ) - TO_DATE(START_DATETIME, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ) + 1 ) )

Comment: You don't need to run `TO_DATE()` on a value which is already a `DATE`. At least `START_DATETIME` seems to be a `DATE` data type. Try `CONNECT BY LEVEL < 24 * (NVL(END_DATETIME, SYSDATE+1/24) - START_DATETIME + 1 )`